# Rshiny App updatetextinput multiple times on one event

Tags: r

I am trying to build a shiny app where with a click of a button 6 codes gets executed. since the processing time is 5-10 mins, to keep the users aware of the process, I want to have a textbox/verbatim box that will change basis which code is run.
"error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'head': object 'x' not found"

Edit : Have changed the code. However the first instance of text is not displayed "data loading".

TIA.

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Testing Textupdate Multiple Times"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
      actionButton("button1","Click"),
      textInput("text1", label = "", value = ""),
      dataTableOutput("table1")
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )  
  ))

server = function(input, output,session) {
  x<-data.frame()
  observeEvent(input$button1, { 
  updateTextInput(session,"text1",value = "Data Loading")
    withProgress(message = 'Data Loading',
                 detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                   for (i in 1:10) {
                     incProgress(1/10)
                     Sys.sleep(0.25)
                   }
                 })
    x<-mtcars
    updateTextInput(session,"text1",value = "Data Loaded")})
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    head(x)})
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `x` is defined locally within an `observeEvent` method; if you move `x <- mtcars` outside of `updateTextInput` either within `server` or in the global environment it should get rid of the error...also, I don't see `button1` in your `ui`, so suspect the `observeEvent` won't get triggered either...

Comment: Thank you Ben. I have modified the code. I no longer get that error. When I run this the textbox value need to be changed, but it is not happening. i can see  only the latest update value.

Comment: I think this is a more difficult issue. The first `updateTextInput` will probably not be executed until the end of the `observeEvent` code block. I might post this as a different question. Also, I'm unclear why the text box is used for status - you mentioned text box/verbatim box - did you just want `verbatimTextOutput` in your `ui`? Or might the user actually input information in an input text box?

Comment: Actually I dont need textinput. The code (6 code files) I am executing takes time in processing, hence I am trying to use verbatimOutput as a way to keep the user aware of the part the code is getting executed. Since all 6 code files are part of same reactive function, hence I am facing difficulty in updating the values.

Comment: I see, thanks. Please see answer below and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updateTextInput` will not be implemented until the end of the `observeEvent`, so the "Data Loading" message will not be seen. However, you can try a `sendCustomMessage` and add javascript to show the text instead. Here is a working example that uses `verbatimTextOutput` instead of a `textInput`. Please let me know if this works for you - I hope it is helpful.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script('
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("status_text", function(text) {
        document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = text;
    })          
  '),
  titlePanel("Testing Textupdate Multiple Times"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
      actionButton("button1", "Click"),
      verbatimTextOutput("text1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("table1")
    )  
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  x <- mtcars
  
  observeEvent(input$button1, { 
    session$sendCustomMessage("status_text", "Data loading...")
    withProgress(message = 'Data Loading',
                 detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                   for (i in 1:10) {
                     incProgress(1/10)
                     Sys.sleep(0.25)
                   }
                 })
    session$sendCustomMessage("status_text", "Data loaded")
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    head(x)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want the `verbatimTextOutput` to be present initially (but without text) you can add this to `server`:

```
output$text1 <- renderText({
  " "
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ben, this is exactly what I needed. Help much appreciated!!!